# There are two tables. i want to join them in such a way that i can get the following result

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
student_mas::                  receipt_mas
name    class                   name     class     month
john     2nd                   john       2nd       JAN
bunny    3rd                   john       2nd       FEB
sunny    4th                   bunny      3rd       FEB
```

student who submits fees for a particular month gets inserted into the second table mentioning the month in the month column in the second table
I want the list of students who have not submitted the fees for the month of JAN
please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **<kbd>[NOT EXISTS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx)</kbd>**

**Query**

```
select * from student_mas t
where not exists (
    select * from receipt_mas 
    where name = t.name
    and class = t.class
    and [month] = 'JAN'
);
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b847c/1)</kbd>**

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DEAR. FINALLY IT WORKED

Answer (score 1):

Ullas answer would work perfectly but you can try like the below approach.

```
DECLARE @student_mas TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,class VARCHAR(10)
    );

insert into @student_mas 
values
('john', '2nd'),
('bunny', '3rd'),
('sunny', '4th');

DECLARE @receipt_mas TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,class VARCHAR(10)
    ,[month] VARCHAR(3)
    );

insert into @receipt_mas
values
('john', '2nd', 'JAN'),
('john', '2nd', 'FEB'),
('bunny', '3rd', 'FEB');

SELECT sm.*
FROM @student_mas sm
LEFT JOIN @receipt_mas rm ON sm.NAME = rm.NAME
    AND sm.class = rm.class
    AND rm.month = 'JAN'
WHERE RM.class IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with student_mas as
(
SELECT 'JOHN' NAME,'2ND' CLASS FROM DUAL
union all
SELECT 'BUNNY' NAME,'3RD' CLASS FROM DUAL
union all
SELECT 'SUNNY' NAME,'4TH' CLASS FROM DUAL
)
select * from student_mas A
where not exists
(
    with receipt_mas as
    (
    SELECT 'JOHN' NAME,'2ND' CLASS,'JAN' MONTH FROM DUAL
    union all
    SELECT 'BUNNY' NAME,'3RD' CLASS,'FEB' MONTH FROM DUAL
    union all
    SELECT 'SUNNY' NAME,'4TH' CLASS,'FEB' MONTH FROM DUAL
    )
    select * from receipt_mas B
    where  A.NAME=B.NAME
    and    A.CLASS=B.CLASS
    and    B.MONTH='JAN'
)
/
```